# Rails - friendly_id - How can I generate friendly_id slug from a text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

rails newbie here I am using friendly_id gem, I have a Page model when I create page a friendly_id slug generate from title given in text field, 
What i want is to able to edit that slug and do not change on update or when i change the title

here is my Page.rb

```
     class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

            belongs_to :user
            include Bootsy::Container

            extend FriendlyId

            friendly_id :title, use: :slugged


            validates :title, :presence => true
            validates :user_id, :presence => true

            def should_generate_new_friendly_id?

            end

          end
```

I know this is a very basic task but I am new in rails. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done this by adding the following login inside `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` :

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  new_record? || !self.slug.present?
end
```